# How to know if there is any way to access data from a stolen Galaxy S3, or Android phone in general, via automatic backup or any other way

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, backup, data-recovery, lost-phone, verizon-backup-assistant

I apologize in advance for my ignorance.  My Verizon Galaxy S3 went missing at a party.  I am hoping that at least some of the data (documents, media, contacts, texts, phone calls...) was backed up automatically at some point after the last time I manually transferred to my laptop.  As I am ridiculously busy, there were many apps that I was not yet acquainted with on my phone.  I am not even aware of what types of software is out there for this or whether or not my phone was equipped with any of it.

Does anyone know of any chance I can still access my data before I talk to Verizon and replace my phone?  Any and all insight is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts and calendar (by default) will be stored with your gmail account.  Most likely when you activate another phone you'll immediately see this data if you activate the gmail (Gooble Play store) with the same account.